# Objects vs selectiong from a database

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object, jdbc

I'm currently working on creating a small shopping cart. I was wondering which method is better to select all my products in one go and storing them as objects or continually selecting them from the database when needed? This is in Java by the way

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most webshops loading them from the database when needed is the way to go. If you are using java and JPA, JPA will do caching for you. So there is no need to cache yourself (keeping inmemory objects). Also it gets really hard to keep all those object in sync (imagine if a manager changes a price or removes a product).

Bottem line, the database and JPA are build for this so use them!

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing your data frequently store it in object. (Ull have only one server call in such case).